# Variable font styling in text tracks in HTML5 Video via CSS

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to change `font-variation-settings` in a `b` tag that I've placed inside a subtitle file that is being called inside a `track` element that is the child of a `video` element:

The HTML file:

```
    <video controls width="640" src="/media/friday.mp4">
      <track default kind="captions" srclang="en" src="/media/friday.vtt">
    </video>
```

the VTT file:

```
00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the <b.strongish>lord of the universe</b> in?
```

I'm attempting to recreate Roel Nieskens' [solution](https://pixelambacht.nl/2019/fixing-variable-font-inheritance/) to deal with the variable font inheritance problem (i.e. the fact that changing values in one axis will make all other non-explicitly defined axes return to their default values). My CSS:

```
:root {
  --wght: 400;
  --mono: 0;
}

video::cue {
  font-variation-settings: "wght" var(--wght), "MONO" var(--mono);
  font-family: "Recursive", sans-serif;
}

video::cue(b.strongish) {
  --mono: 1;
}
```

The idea is that by changing `--mono`'s value in the `.strongish` class, this would override the value set on `::root` while retaining the previously set value for `--wght`.

This works when I use it to style any other HTML tag, but not inside `video::cue`. The issue isn't with the `font-variation-settings` property, because if I set it manually, without the CSS variables, it works fine (e.g. `font-variation-settiongs: 'MONO' 1;`).

Do CSS variables not work in video subtitles? If they do, can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note: the `<track>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash.

Comment: thanks! this was added by the code linter, but removing it didn't solve this particular issue.

Comment: I didn't think it would fix anything. I was just noting that the closing slash is not used in HTML. Your linter needs fixing.

Comment: sure. will look into that

Answer (score 2):

The `font-variations-settings` is applied to the `video::cue` element, and will apply the values of `wght` and `MONO` as they were *at that time* for itself and its children.

But there is no `font-variations-settings` being set in the `b.strongish` child of `video::cue`. So even though you correctly set `--mono: 1;`, there is no `font-variations-settings` to actually pick up that changed variable, so changing it has no effect.

You can try to change this bit:

```
video::cue {
  font-variation-settings: "wght" var(--wght), "MONO" var(--mono);
  font-family: "Recursive", sans-serif;
}
```

to:

```
video::cue,
video::cue * {
  font-variation-settings: "wght" var(--wght), "MONO" var(--mono);
  font-family: "Recursive", sans-serif;
}
```

which should apply `font-variation-settings` to the child elements as well, where it'll pick up the changed variable and render the text as you expect.

Let me know if that works.

By the way, pretty cool to stumble upon a question that references a post on my site, thanks! :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay! It didn't work, but I'm guessing it has more to do with `font-variation-settings` not being an allowed property for `video::cue` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::cue))

The way I'm dealing with this is hiding the video cue and using a <div> overlaid on the video player :-(

Comment: I mean, it kind of works — I am able to set the variables once and they are rendered... so maybe the problem is still in how I'm doing my declarations? 

Btw, `video::cue *` didn't work for some reason (when I have it the whole rule is ignored by the browser), but I replaced with the more specific `video::cue(b)`.